# How can I configure the VS Code Code Runner extension to use the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vscode-code-runner

I wanted to know how I can set the code runner extension to use the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler. By default, trying to run the code throws an error as it is set to use the g++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change [the `code-runner.executorMap` setting](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration). You can either do this in your user or workspace [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). I believe you'd want something like so:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "cpp": "cd $dir && cl $fileName /link /out:$fileNameWithoutExt.exe && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

You can adjust it and add other commandline flags as needed (Ex `/W4`, `/EHsc`)

You might need to run VS Code from a Visual Studio Developer prompt to get a working environment.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line